# suppress findpeaks warnings in MATLAB Signal Processing Toolbox

Tags: matlab

I use the function [findpeaks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/findpeaks.html) from MATLAB's Signal Processing Toolbox. But everytime the function does not find any peaks I receive the warning:

```
Warning: No peaks found. 
> In findpeaks at 83
```

Now I have to handle those cases anyway and therefore check if the vector returned by `findpeaks` is empty. So I would like to suppress those warnings, because I don't want my Command Window to get cluttered up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First identify the warning id:

```
findpeaks([1 1 1 1 ]);
[msg id] = lastwarn;
```

Then switch off the warning:

```
warning('off',id)
```