# Silencing warning messages in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Sometimes, depending on the size of an image, when I call [`addframe`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/avifile.addframe.html) in MATLAB to add 2D images to a video, I get the following warning message.

> Warning: The frame height has been padded to be a multiple of four as
>   required by the specified codec. 
>   In avifile.addframe at 127

My questions are:

1. Are there any ways of **silencing specific warnings** like this? If so, is it possible to **capture a warning** in a variable in my code (i.e. similar to the try & catch exception mechanism) rather than having MATLAB print this warning in the command window?
2. If the above is not possible. Is it there a way to **silence all warnings** in MATLAB **temporarily**?

Comment: try the solutions in these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408759/avoid-matlab-startup-warning-when-overloading-buildin-functions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333949/suppress-findpeaks-warnings-in-matlab-signal-processing-toolbox

Comment: Alternatively, you could pad the frame height yourself to a multiple of four as required by the specified codec...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the `warning` command, you can silence either all warnings or specific warnings by ID:

> `WARNING('OFF', 'MSGID')` and `WARNING('ON', 'MSGID')` disable and enable the
>   display of any warning tagged with message identifier `MSGID`. (Use `LASTWARN`
>   to determine the identifier of a warning, or use the `WARNING VERBOSE` feature
>   described below.) `WARNING` is not case sensitive when matching message
>   identifiers.

For more help on the `warning` command, type `help warning` in the MATLAB command line.